# Code completion for constructor parameter types

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I often have to inject dependencies in some class:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is a code completion for a `UserService` type when I'm typing `userService`:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(private userSer) { // <-- suggests UserService type so I can get the previous code example
  }
}
```

I know it is possible with Kotlin and IntelliJ IDEA but I'm wondering whether it is possible with TypeScript and WebStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion**, **JavaScript**, try enabling both **Suggest variable and parameter names** and **Add type annotations for suggested parameter names** - does it help?

Comment: It works, thank you! I don't know how I could've missed that checkbox...